# Глобальные переменные в golang

Tags: golang

У меня есть структура типа:

```
type AuthUser struct {
    Id int
    Name string
    Password string
}
```

Я хочу объявить переменную `var AuthUsersList map[string]*AuthUser`
Но такой способ выдаёт ошибку при попытке позже в неё  что то записать. В документации пишут что должно быть так `AuthUsersList := make(map[string]*AuthUser)`
Но так работает только в пределах функции, а я хочу что бы эта переменная была глобальной. Как так сделать?

Comment: `var AuthUsersList = make(map[string]*AuthUser)`

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, [соблюдайте стиль!](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#initialisms) `ID` вместо `Id`.

Во-вторых,

```
var AuthUsersList = map[string]*AuthUser{}
```

Либо, если сразу хотите выделить места,

```
const numUser = 1024
var AuthUsersList = make(map[string]*AuthUser, numUser)
```

Comment: Второй вариант позволяет избежать переформирования карты, когда среднее число элементов в букете превосходит некоторое пороговое значение, что довольно полезно в отдельных ситуациях. Когда-то задавал вопрос о том, какие языки так могут. Оказывается, Go может.